# Failed to start Kafka after enabling Kerberos "SASL authentication failed"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, sasl

Kafka version: kafka_2.1.1(binary)

When I enable the Kerberos I follow the official documents(https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_kerberos) closely.

When I start the Kafka, I got the following errors:

```
[2019-02-23 08:55:44,622] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:805)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:94)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1145)
[2019-02-23 08:55:44,625] ERROR [ZooKeeperClient] Auth failed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-02-23 08:55:44,746] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

I use almost the default krb5.conf.

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 pkinit_anchors = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
 default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
#  kdc = kerberos.example.com
#  admin_server = kerberos.example.com
  kdc = localhost
  admin_server = localhost
 }

[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

The jaas file I passed to the Kafka is as below:

```
KafkaServer {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/localhost.keytab"
    principal="kafka/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM";
};

// Zookeeper client authentication
Client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/localhost.keytab"
principal="kafka/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

I also set the ENV as below:

```
"-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf -Dzookeeper.sasl.client.username=kafka"
```

I have googled a lot of posts but without any progress. I guess the problem may be the "localhost" I use when I create entries in Kerberos. But I'm not quite sure how to workaround. The goal for me is to setup a local Kafka+Kerberos testing environment.

Comment: Have you followed step 3 and step 4

Comment: There are 3 steps under section "Authentication using SASL/Kerberos". I followed "Prerequisites" and "Configuring Kafka Brokers". But I didn't do the last one "Configuring Kafka Clients" because the last one is for clients (producers, consumers, connect workers, etc).

Comment: In Configuring Kafka Brokers did you follow step 3 and step 4

Answer (score 0):

```
In our case, the krb5 kerberos_config file wasn't read properly. if you're using keytab thru' yml then it'd need to be removed first. This was with IBM JDK though and had to use the following to set System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", JaasConfigFileLocation);

KafkaClient {
com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useDefaultKeytab=false
credsType=both
principal="xkafka@xxx.NET"
useKeytab="/opt/apps/xxxr/my.keytab";
};
```